# Difference between SIGKILL SIGTERM considering process tree

Tags: linux, thread-safety, signals

What is the difference between `SIGTERM` and `SIGKILL` when it comes to the process tree?
When a root thread receives `SIGKILL` does it get killed cleanly or does it leave it's child threads as zombies?
Is there any signal which can be sent to a root thread to cleanly exit by not leaving any zombie threads ?

Thanks.

Comment: There's a separate system call for killing entire process groups: `killpg`.  Also it's important to be clear about the difference between *threads* and *processes* in Linux - they're different things.

Comment: [![The Real Reason to Not Use SIGKILL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnEqw.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnEqw.png) Probably you want to keep this comic in mind. Source : http://turnoff.us/geek/dont-sigkill/

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042201/how-does-sigint-relate-to-the-other-termination-signals/29659703#29659703

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you kill the root process (parent process), this should make orphan children, not zombie children.  orphan children are made when you kill a process's parent, and the kernel makes init the parent of orphans.  init is supposed to wait until orphan dies, then use wait to clean it up.

Zombie children are created when a process (not its parent) ends and its parent does not take up its exit status from the process table.

It sounds to me like you are worried about leaving orphans because by definition, when you kill a zombies parent process, the zombie child itself dies.

To kill your orphans, use kill -9 , which is the equivalent SIGKILL.

Here is a more in depth tutorial for killing stuff on linux:
http://riccomini.name/posts/linux/2012-09-25-kill-subprocesses-linux-bash/

Answer (score 1):

You can't control that by signal; only its parent process can control that, by calling `waitpid()` or setting signal handlers for `SIGCHLD`.  See `SIGCHLD` and `SA_NOCLDWAIT` in the `sigaction(2)` manpage for details.

Also, what happens to child threads depends on the Linux kernel version.  With 2.6's POSIX threads, killing the main thread should cause the other threads to exit cleanly.  With 2.4 LinuxThreads, each thread is actually a separate process and `SIGKILL` doesn't give the root thread a chance to tell the others to shut down, whereas `SIGTERM` does.