# stop shell script in background by sending signal

Tags: bash, signals

I have a bash shell script `S1` that starts another shell script `S2` (contains just `sleep 20`) synchronously, i.e. in the foreground.

What I want is the following:

When I send SIGTERM or SIGINT to `S1`, both `S1` and `S2` should stop.

Actually that works if I start `S1` on the command line in the foreground an if I press CTRL-C (independent of whether I trap SIGINT in the scripts explicitly or not).

When I start `S1` in the background and then send it the SIGINT signal with `kill -s SIGINT $!` it takes until `S2` terminates its normal processing, i.e. `S2` is not interrupted.

My use case is the latter and I a need a way to interrupt both `S1` and `S2` by sending a signal just to `S1`.

Comment: searching for `[unix] SIGINT` returned numerous promising answers. Particularly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042201/how-does-sigint-relate-to-the-other-termination-signals. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

S1.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

on_term()
{
    echo "S1: Sending TERM to S2.sh"
    pkill -TERM S2.sh
    echo "S1: Waiting for S2 to complete..."
}

trap "on_term" TERM

echo "S1: Forking a child..."

./S2.sh &

while [ 1 == 1 ]; do
    wait
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        break
    fi
done

echo "S1: Done!"
```

S2.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

on_term()
{
    echo "S2: Terminating..."
    exit -1
}

trap "on_term" TERM

echo "S2: Sleeping..."

sleep 5

echo "S2: Done!"
```

Have fun!

Comment: You should use `$!` rather than shutting down any process with a certain name.

Comment: Of course, starting S2 in the background is a solution. But can I achieve the same without starting S2 in the background? Why is the behavior different as I described above (ctrl-c when S1 runs in foreground vs. "kill -s SIGINT" when S1 was started in the background)?

Answer (score 2):

If you are starting `S1` from the command line, then send the signal to all processes in the process group using a job specification starting with %, for example `kill -INT %+`.

If you are starting `S1` from another script `S3`, perhaps it should terminate with `S1` and `S2` on `SIGINT`, which reduces to the above. Otherwise, you can try using job control like

```
set -m
S1 &
set +m
pid=$!
...
kill -INT -- -$pid
```

but this may not work reliably with all shells, or if there is no controlling terminal. Manually forwarding the signal as in Ilya's answer is an alternative.