# Is `SIGKILL` called on a thread when it terminates?

Tags: linux, multithreading, unix, pthreads, sigkill

Does `SIGKILL` get called on a unix thread when it terminates?

I'm monitoring an application which might be using a threadpool and registering a `SIGKILL` handler with a `printf` shows nothing. I'm trying to understand if there's a threadpool involved or not (if there is, the threads are never terminated and it makes sense not to read any output at all).

Comment: *registering a `SIGKILL` handler* `SIGKILL`?  As in `-9`?  You're wasting your time - [you can't catch `SIGKILL`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35569659/the-signals-sigkill-and-sigstop-cannot-be-caught-blocked-or-orignored-why)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does `SIGKILL` get called on a unix thread when it terminates?

Nope.

One can send `SIGKILL` to a thread but well-behaved application do not and should not do that. The threads had better terminate in a cooperative fashion when they are told to by leaving the thread function or calling `pthread_exit`.

> ... registering a `SIGKILL` handler with a `printf` shows nothing

`SIGKILL` cannot be blocked or caught.