# how does the process know the SIGQUIT signal?

Tags: linux, job-control

It's said that the `SIGQUIT` signal cannot be caught by process,but the process response according to the signal which it catches,so why do process can be quitted by `SIGQUIT`?The process even don't catch(know) the signal

Comment: I think you're mixing up SIGQUIT with SIGKILL, also this may help? In the case of SIGKILL the process never gets the signal and the system (the [linux] kernel) terminates the process).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042201/how-does-sigint-relate-to-the-other-termination-signals-such-as-sigterm-sigquit

Comment: It's `SIGKILL` that cannot be caught, not `SIGQUIT`.

Comment: For signals that can be caught, a process can set a trap or signal handler that gets called when the process receives that signal. For SIGKILL, the OS just terminates the process without looking for any signal handlers.