# How to force kill a node child process started with exec?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm starting a process in a node app, running on Windows, which I cannot kill. I'm using [node's `exec`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processexeccommand-options-callback) which requires a command line parameter (thus I cannot use `spawn`). Normally this process runs without ending, expecting a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> from the user to end it. I want to instead programmatically end it from within node.

For a simplified example of the scenario:

```js
import { exec } from 'child_process'; // (Note that this is an ESM/module type file)
// Start the process (in this example, it runs a local server)
const serverProcess = exec('cordova run browser --port=1234');
// Wait a bit, and then try to kill the process
setTimeout(() => {
    serverProcess.kill();
    // also tried: process.kill(serverProcess.pid);
    console.log(serverProcess.killed);
    // Will log as true, but the process continues to run,
    // requiring Ctrl+C on the node program
}, 5000);
```

*Edit:* I have tried using different signals for kill, including setting `killSignal` in the options, but that has not remedied the problem. According to [the node docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#subprocesskillsignal):

> On Windows, where POSIX signals do not exist, the signal argument will be ignored, and the process will be killed forcefully and abruptly (similar to 'SIGKILL').

Comment: The default `killSignal` is `SIGTERM` (which can be intercepted by the process). (Note this is not the same as `SIGINT` which is sent by ctrl + c in a TTY.) Try setting `killSignal` to `SIGKILL` (which cannot be ignored by the process). Read more about signals at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4042201/438273).

Comment: @jfriend00 - That was a typo that I've fixed.

Comment: @jsejcksn - Changing kill signals did not help. I added an edit to the question explaining this.

Comment: Not sure why you say you cannot use `spawn`, but it definitely takes command line args as well: `spawn("cordova", ["run", "browser", "--port=1234"])`

Comment: Also which process keeps running? The `node` process or the `cordova` process?

Comment: Tangent to your question: you'll probably find it quite helpful to develop using [containers](https://hub.docker.com/search?q=cordova).